# Preventing execution of sudo rm -rf /*

Tags: linux, sudo, root, rm

Do any Linux distros prevent the execution of `sudo rm -rf /*` so that people do not accidentally delete their hard drives if they did not know what they are doing?

Comment: Shoot. that's a cron job of mine. Keeps the box virus free! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; you are expected to know what you are doing. Look on the bright side! You almost certainly won't shoot yourself in the foot more than once.

Comment: Well... maybe twice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not by default.

Let me add that the risk can be more subtle than your bare-bones example.  Take this example:

```
[user@server ~]$ sudo rm -rf directory_to_delete /*
```

The accidental space between the `directory_to_delete` and the `/*` means that it's going to operate on both the `directory_to_delete` **and** `/*`, the root folder, as the root user.  And it's going to do it recursively, so there goes your OS install.

That's why you need to be **extremely** careful when using `rm -rf`, especially with `sudo`.